# Problem with DataFrame_Image No such file or directory: ...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpm56n0wp6\\temp.png

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
ubicacion = "C:.../Desktop/Informes/names/"
nombrepng= "name.png"

def df_to_image(df, ubicacion, nombre):
    if os.path.exists(ubicacion+nombre):
        os.remove(ubicacion+nombre)
        dfi.export(df, ubicacion+nombre)
    else:
        dfi.export(df, ubicacion+nombre)

df_to_image(df, ubicacion, nombrepng)
```

When i try to save a dataframe in a png it gives me this error:

```
    File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dataframe_image\_screenshot.py", line 158, in possibly_enlarge
        return self.take_screenshot()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dataframe_image\_screenshot.py", line 135, in take_screenshot
        with open(temp_img, "rb") as f:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpm56n0wp6\\temp.png'
```

What is very strange is that yesterday it worked correctly for me and today it gives me that error for almost all the scripts in which create a png. A few still work for me but most don't.

On my other computer they work perfectly but on the notebook they don't. I already tried to reinstall all the libraries and python

Comment: Perhaps try creating a static location for your images first, some folder within the same folder that contains your code and go from there.

Comment: chris I already define in my code a place where I want to save the image. The problem is that the library temporarily creates a file called temp.png in the temp folder and I don't know why sometimes it wouldn't be creating it for me, so it throws me that error

Comment: OMG I am getting the same error at the moment, and can't believe this question was asked 3 hours ago

Comment: And 2 weeks ago, the same code worked fine (don't have locked requirements.txt so maybe some updated dependency broke it?)

Comment: same problem here omg

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The specific problem is when I want to create the png image of a dataframe I get that error that is generated because the library tries to create a random folder with an image called temp.png inside and I don't know why since today in some scripts it works and in Many others throw me that error. Please, if someone manages to solve it, comment on this post.

Comment: same problem for me too. likely an update error. something similar happened couple of months ago.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue on github: https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image/issues/79

The workaround proposed here worked for me, by just using option `table_conversion='matplotlib'` :
https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image/issues/79#issuecomment-1468371096

```
dfi.export(df, "table.png", table_conversion='matplotlib')
```

However I lost the colorization of my styled dataframe.

Comment: I tried adding table_conversion='matplotlib' but I got the following error message: "FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?". I have installed the dependencies (pandas, nbconvert, requests, matplotlib, BeautifulSoup, aiohttp) as well as lxml. Do I also need to import all of these packages into my python file? Otherwise, what could I be missing?

Comment: works but why??

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding "matplotlib" but the coloring was lost, making it useless.

I solved it by adding fontsize and dpi in export,

example:

```
dfi.export(df, "table.png", fontsize=8, dpi=150)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Given that this was the second time this year that the library stopped working, we have decided to rewrite out scripts to utilize different tools. We used to use this library for daily reporting, but our new solution seems to be more stable.

We switched over to using `openpyxl` to build/format our tables using excel, and then use `excel2img` to export the image into a .png file.

I know that it is not really a direct solution to the problem you've been experiencing, but after spending a few weeks trying every solution people had suggested in GitHub, switching over to `openpyxl` was the best solution we came up with.

I cannot share too much detail about our scripts, but here are the libraries we are using:

```
from PIL import Image   
import PIL  
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, colors, Color, Alignment, PatternFill, GradientFill, Border, Side
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting import Rule
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScale, FormatObject
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis
from openpyxl.drawing.spreadsheet_drawing import TwoCellAnchor

import excel2img
```

Here is a brief example of how we are using these libraries to achieve a similar result as what we had when using `dataframe_image`:

```
header_rows = [1, 2]
for i in columns:
    for j in header_rows:
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='003F89')
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].font = Font(bold=True, color='FFFFFF', name='Arial')

ws['E2'].fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='0000FF')

percent_cols = ['B', 'D', 'H']
dat_rows = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in percent_cols:
    for j in dat_rows:
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].number_format = '0.0%'
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)

for i in dat_rows:
    ws['E{}'.format(i)].number_format = '0'
    ws['E{}'.format(i)].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)

for i in dat_rows:
    ws['C{}'.format(i)].number_format = '0,000'

base_10_cols = ['F', 'G', 'I']
for i in base_10_cols:
    for j in dat_rows:
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].number_format = '0.00'
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)

eh_first = FormatObject(type='num', val=.6)
eh_last = FormatObject(type='num', val=1)
eh_mid = FormatObject(type='num', val=.8)
colors = [Color('F8696B'), Color('FFFFFF'), Color('5A8AC6')]
eh_cs3 = ColorScale(cfvo=[eh_first, eh_mid, eh_last], color=colors)
eh_rule = Rule(type='colorScale', colorScale=eh_cs3)
eh_style = Font(bold=True, name='Arial')
eh_rule2 = Rule(type='expression', formula=['B3>={}'.format(a1)], dxf=DifferentialStyle(font=Font(bold=True, name='Arial')))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('B3:B10', eh_rule)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('B3:B10', eh_rule2)

cm_style = Font(bold=True, name='Arial')
cm_rule2 = Rule(type='expression', formula=['D3>={}'.format(b1)], dxf=DifferentialStyle(font=Font(bold=True, name='Arial')))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('D3:D10', cm_rule2)

co_first = FormatObject(type='num', val=918)
co_last = FormatObject(type='num', val=1000)
co_mid = FormatObject(type='num', val=959)
co_cs3 = ColorScale(cfvo=[co_first, co_mid, co_last], color=colors)
co_rule = Rule(type='colorScale', colorScale=co_cs3)
co_style = Font(bold=True, name='Arial')
co_rule2 = Rule(type='expression', formula=['E3>={}'.format(c1)], dxf=DifferentialStyle(font=Font(bold=True, name='Arial')))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('E3:E10', co_rule)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('E3:E10', co_rule2)

de_first = FormatObject(type='num', val=9.5)
de_last = FormatObject(type='num', val=10)
de_mid = FormatObject(type='num', val=9.75)
de_cs3 = ColorScale(cfvo=[de_first, de_mid, de_last], color=colors)
de_rule = Rule(type='colorScale', colorScale=de_cs3)
de_style = Font(bold=True, name='Arial')
de_rule2 = Rule(type='expression', formula=['F3>={}'.format(d1)], dxf=DifferentialStyle(font=Font(bold=True, name='Arial')))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('F3:F10', de_rule)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('F3:F10', de_rule2)

ag_first = FormatObject(type='num', val=9.3)
ag_last = FormatObject(type='num', val=10)
ag_mid = FormatObject(type='num', val=9.65)
ag_cs3 = ColorScale(cfvo=[ag_first, ag_mid, ag_last], color=colors)
ag_rule = Rule(type='colorScale', colorScale=ag_cs3)
ag_style = Font(bold=True, name='Arial')
ag_rule2 = Rule(type='expression', formula=['G3>={}'.format(e1)], dxf=DifferentialStyle(font=Font(bold=True, name='Arial')))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('G3:G10', ag_rule)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('G3:G10', ag_rule2)

ti_first = FormatObject(type='num', val=0.48)
ti_last = FormatObject(type='num', val=1)
ti_mid = FormatObject(type='num', val=.74)
ti_cs3 = ColorScale(cfvo=[ti_first, ti_mid, ti_last], color=colors)
ti_rule = Rule(type='colorScale', colorScale=ti_cs3)
ti_style = Font(bold=True, name='Arial')
ti_rule2 = Rule(type='expression', formula=['H3>={}'.format(f1)], dxf=DifferentialStyle(font=Font(bold=True, name='Arial')))


ws.conditional_formatting.add('H3:H10', ti_rule)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('H3:H10', ti_rule2)

fa_first = FormatObject(type='num', val=9.1)
fa_last = FormatObject(type='num', val=10)
fa_mid = FormatObject(type='num', val=9.55)
fa_cs3 = ColorScale(cfvo=[fa_first, fa_mid, fa_last], color=colors)
fa_rule = Rule(type='colorScale', colorScale=fa_cs3)
fa_style = Font(bold=True, name='Arial')
fa_rule2 = Rule(type='expression', formula=['I3>={}'.format(x1)], dxf=DifferentialStyle(font=Font(bold=True, name='Arial')))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('I3:I10', fa_rule)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('I3:I10', fa_rule2)

nf_cols = ['A', 'C', 'D']
for i in nf_cols:
    for j in dat_rows:
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='FFFFFF')
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j)].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)

thin_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin', color='FFFFFF'), 
                     right=Side(style='thin', color='FFFFFF'), 
                     top=Side(style='thin', color='FFFFFF'), 
                     bottom=Side(style='thin', color='FFFFFF'))

for i in columns:
    for j in range(10):
        ws['{}{}'.format(i,j+1)].border = thin_border

ws['E2'].border = Border(left=Side(style='thin', color='000000'), 
                     right=Side(style='thin', color='000000'), 
                     top=Side(style='thin', color='000000'))

for i in [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
    ws['E{}'.format(i)].border = Border(left=Side(style='thin', color='000000'), 
                                        right=Side(style='thin', color='000000'))
    
ws['E10'].border = Border(bottom=Side(style='thin', color='000000'),
                            left=Side(style='thin', color='000000'), 
                            right=Side(style='thin', color='000000'))
```

And for the export:

```
#export tables as images
excel2img.export_img("excel_file_name.xlsx","image_1.png", "","sheet_name!A1:I10")
excel2img.export_img("excel_file_name.xlsx","image_2.png", "","sheet_name2!A1:I10")
```

I hope this helps.